# Commit instead of rollback?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Simple example (PSEUDO CODE):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    START TRANSACTION;  
    SELECT id, name FROM employees WHERE id = i;

  
    IF (someFunction(id)) {
        ROLLBACK;
        CONTINUE; // GO TO NEXT EXECUTION OF FOR LOOP
    }

    UPDATE company SET good = good + 1;

    COMMIT;
}
```

Can I use in this example COMMIT (so I'm gonna have two COMMIT in my script) instead of ROLLBACK?

Does it make any difference to the database if I use COMMIT instead of ROLLBACK after select?

Is there any difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL here?

Comment: does someFunction use the database?

Comment: @ysth no, someFunction does not use the database.

Comment: so for every id you start a new transaction, so the cmit makes nothing at all as doesn the rollback in your cqase as it is only 1 comand

Comment: Your pseudo-code makes little sense.  Based on what you've posted here I'd be looking to perform whatever `someFunction(id)` does as part of the `UPDATE` query and do away with the whole `START TRANSACTION | COMMIT | ROLLBACK` thing altogether.

Comment: Just omit `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` and commit the transaction after your code is done.

Comment: it is not clear what you hope to accomplish by having the select inside the transaction in the first place, or by having a separate transaction for each iteration of the loop.  if you were to provide more information, you would get better advice

Answer (score 2):

`Select` by itself does not require either rollback nor commit. Those are needed only after DML (insert, update, delete). Further it is typically considered better to have only 1 commit in a transaction. The idea being the entire transaction completely succeeds or completely as a unit. so your pseudo code  becomes:

```
START TRANSACTION;   
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    SELECT id, name FROM employees WHERE id = i;

    IF NOT (someFunction(id)) {
       UPDATE company SET good = good + 1;  
    }
}
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Probably better to do `SELECT id, name FROM employees WHERE ( id >= 0 AND id < 100 )`, then iterate through each fetched row. That would avoid multiple `SELECT` calls, which are more expensive than simply fetching results from a query which has already been performed.

Comment: This is not entirely true. In Postgres SELECT starts a transaction if autocommit is disabled and to end that transaction you would need a commit or rollback, otherwise the connection remains the state "idle in transaction". In MySQL when autocommit is disabled, it might also be necessary to end a transaction started by a SELECT to see changes done by other transactions if the default REPEATABLE READ isolation is in effect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in my example do I have to use commit or rollback if the example will work on two databases and it does not matter if I use commit or rollback? Please add a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I understand your question to be asking if ROLLBACK or COMMIT is better when, after only a select, you determine that no changes are going to be made in this transaction.

As far as mysql is concerned, there's no reason to do either rollback or commit; since no changes have been made, neither does anything, and doing neither causes no issues.  But it is not clear what you hope to accomplish by having the select inside the transaction in the first place, or by having a separate transaction for each iteration of the loop.  If you were to provide more information, you would get better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation of @Belayer's answer, in which I made the following changes:

1. Perform a single `SELECT`, with the intention of reducing the number of queries
2. Keep a running total of the number of times `company.good` should be incremented, before finally incrementing it with a single `UPDATE`.

```
new_good = 0;
SELECT id, name FROM employees WHERE id >= 0 AND i < 100
for each fetched row {
    IF NOT (someFunction(id)) {
       new_good++;
    }
}
START TRANSACTION /* Probably not needed */
UPDATE company SET good = good + new_good;  
COMMIT /* Probably not needed */;
```

This probably eliminates the need for a transaction entirely, since any failed call to `SELECT` or fetch will result in no change to `new_good`, so when it eventually gets to the `UPDATE`, `new_good` will still contain a valid value (even if 0).